# How to use Reachability in xcode for assessment Internet Connection

Tags: ios, objective-c, networking

Im new in iphone and I want know that how to use Reachability in xcode.
I go on to [Reachability example](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html) and read about it but understand about it.
I create one application and put Reachability.m and Reachability.h in it but I dont know how to use from it.

please guide me. I want when run application check my network Connection any time and run this code :

```
if (isConnection)
{
NSLog(@"Connection Success")
}
else
NSLog(@"Connection has been lost")
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
 Reachability *reachability = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection];
 NetworkStatus internetStatus = [reachability currentReachabilityStatus];
```

And now check the `internetStatus` var, by inspecting its value. The values are defined as:

```
typedef enum 
{
    // Apple NetworkStatus Compatible Names.
    NotReachable     = 0,
    ReachableViaWiFi = 2,
    ReachableViaWWAN = 1
} NetworkStatus;
```

So, in your case:

```
if (internetStatus == NotReachable)
{
   NSLog(@"Bazinga!");
}
else
{
   NSLog(@"Houston we have ignition");
}
```

Comment: my friend when I add Reachability.m and Reachability.h in my project I get many errors !!! why?

Comment: You probably forgot to add the `SystemConfiguration` framework.

Comment: my friend right error(errors was ARC). I have last question and is : is working this when my application to be in task manager and I run again???

Comment: You will probably need to disable ARC for this specific class. If this is working on the background (when you press the Home button), is that your question?

Comment: I tell Does that work in background (when I press the Home button)?

Comment: For a **brief** period of time, you will be able to run processes while your application is in background. But you shouldn't rely on that to make important operations.

Comment: my friend internetStatus always 2 and never 0 why?

Comment: It means that he his connect then.

Comment: I know dear friend I tell when first turn off wifi from mac this code get me this massage is UILable "NO Internet" then when that application is task manager and me turn on wifi and run again application I dont see that UILable to be change and show me this massage "YES Internet"

Comment: As I told you, some parts of the application won't run if the app is in background.

Comment: sorry my friend now you are angry from me ... Im so sorry!!! my friend  not way that do this work??? (I want my application like mail application(for example gmail or yahoo) this application always check network and update self data even if in task manager)

Comment: It's different. I guess they work with notifications and the app is able to know that they received something. Besides that. Mail probably has access to things that a common developer doesn't have.

Answer (score 0):

Download Reachability Classes and Follow this code

```
internetReach = [[Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection] retain];
[internetReach startNotifier];
```

Then we’ll set the NetworkStatus variable created in Reachability.

```
NetworkStatus netStatus = [internetReach currentReachabilityStatus];
```

And finally we’ll use the netStatus in a switch block.

```
switch (netStatus)
{            
    case ReachableViaWWAN:
    {
        break;
    }
    case ReachableViaWiFi:
    {
        break;
    }
    case NotReachable:
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert" message:@"We are unable to make a internet connection at this time. Some functionality will be limited until a connection is made." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
        [alert show];   
        [alert release];
        break;
    }

}

- (void) reachabilityChanged: (NSNotification* )note
{
    Reachability* curReach = [note object];
    NSParameterAssert([curReach isKindOfClass: [Reachability class]]);

    NetworkStatus netStatus = [curReach currentReachabilityStatus];
    switch (netStatus)
    {
        case ReachableViaWWAN:
        {
            break;
        }
        case ReachableViaWiFi:
        {
            break;
        }
        case NotReachable:
        {
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert" message:@"We are unable to make a internet connection at this time. Some functionality will be limited until a connection is made." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
            [alert show];   
            [alert release];
            break;
        }
    }
}
```